# Socket.io RangeError: Array buffer allocation failed

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

Sending large files through socket.io crashes server with message

```
server > RangeError: Array buffer allocation failed               │
server >     at Buffer.Uint8Array (native)                        │
server >     at FastBuffer (buffer.js:12:5)                       │
server >     at createUnsafeBuffer (buffer.js:39:12)              │
server >     at arrayBufferToBuffer (/home/htdocs/socket/server/  │
node_modules/engine.io-parser/lib/index.js:371:16)                │
server >     at Object.exports.decodePacket (/home/htdocs/socket  │
/server/node_modules/engine.io-parser/lib/index.js:159:12)        │
server >     at WebSocket.Transport.onData (/home/htdocs/socket/  │
server/node_modules/engine.io/lib/transport.js:116:24)            │
server >     at WebSocket.onData (/home/htdocs/socket/server/nod  │
e_modules/engine.io/lib/transports/websocket.js:79:30)            │
server >     at onServerMessage (/home/htdocs/socket/server/node  │
_modules/uws/uws.js:18:15)
```

So it's "open" vulnerability for my application, filtering files by size on client side isn't possible, because client written on JavaScript, and user can easily modify it, is it possible to somehow disable accepting large request node.js/socket.io side?

Nginx used for load balancing, so maybe it's possible to configure nginx to invalidate large requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by passing maxHttpBufferSize (maxPayload in ws) parameter (in bytes)

```
const io = require('socket.io')(port, {
    'maxHttpBufferSize': 1000000
});
```

in case of DoS or just too big file, socket will be disconnected from the server, and server will continue to work fine.